# How to get labels from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to implement the following example code, but the lesson I am referencing isn't quite clear. I know I am loading in data as a CSV file, but I am not sure if the `dataframe.label` was supposed to return the row labels or column labels. Additionally, I cannot figure out how to replace it with working code. I have tried using `iloc`, `.columns`, `.to_numpy()`, `.as_matrix()` all to no avail, and part of my struggle is determining what exactly .label did at one point (or was supposed to do). Here is the lesson I am referencing:
https://www.kaggle.com/dansbecker/deep-learning-from-scratch

and here is the code:

```
def data_prep(raw):
    out_y = keras.utils.to_categorical(raw.label, num_classes)

    num_images = raw.shape[0]
    x_as_array = raw.values[:,1:]
    x_shaped_array = x_as_array.reshape(num_images, img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    out_x = x_shaped_array / 255
    return out_x, out_y

train_file = "../input/digit-recognizer/train.csv"
raw_data = pd.read_csv(train_file)

x, y = data_prep(raw_data)
```

The original error I got was:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'label'

Can anyone shed some light into this?

Comment: "label" is the name of a column. Check your csv file to make sure it has a column named label.

Comment: `raw.label` would access the column `label` in the `raw` dataframe. Output your input dataframe to see if it has such column.

Comment: I think `raw.label` is equivalent to `raw['label']` so it will return a pandas.Series of a column named 'label' from your dataframe.